# Difficulty writing object to file

Tags: java, serialization, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to read a map of Students from a txt file, after that I add a new student to the map (now is bigger than before) and save it back to the file. After I close my program and reload the data from file, the new students weren't saved.

```
HashMap<String, Student> studentObj = new HashMap<>(SIZE);

try {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME)); 
    studentObj = (HashMap<String, Student>) in.readObject();            
    studentObj.put(student.getStudentID(), student);

    ObjectOutputStream out;
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME)));
    out.writeObject(studentObj);
    out.flush();
    System.out.println("here " + studentObj.size());
    in.close();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new Exception("FILE IS NOT CREATED");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new Exception("CLASS NOT FOUND EXCPETION");
}
```

Comment: Print the stack trace of the exceptions: `e.printStackTrace()`. This will tell you about issues encountered.

Comment: I recommend to process the data and save it e.g. as a text file instead of using `ObjectOutputStream`. You could for-loop, save the data into arrays, and save them in a way that lets you read them again properly.

Comment: There's no real point in catching various exceptions then throwing them as basic Exceptions. Either handle those exceptions or make your method throw those specific Exceptions or simply `throws Exception`, if you don't care what kind they are. If you print the stack trace of your exceptions, then you'll see where your problem lies.

Comment: This is the first time I see an exception being thrown from the catch blocks this way and I do not like it. At least add the original exception as cause!

Comment: Also, tip: use [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) blocks rather than explicit closure of streams.

Comment: issue may be related to implement  Serializable interface

Comment: It may be useful to include your `Student` class here too.

Comment: Serialized data is not text and should not be saved in a file named .txt. You haven't described an actual problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was ok. The problem was that after saving the object to the file, then I closed the app and opened it again. Then, the constructor created a new file that overrides the old one. I added an if statement to create the file just for the first time. I used txt to make it simple and fast because is just a small task. I love to use xml files instead :) And yes, JAVA can save objects.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @xdevs23

Instead of saving the data into arrays (which will use more memory), you could write

```
/*import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;*/

HashMap<String, Student> studentObj = new HashMap<>(SIZE);

try{

    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME)); 
    studentObj = (HashMap<String, Student>) in.readObject();            
    studentObj.put(student.getStudentID(), student);
    in.close();
    System.out.println("here " + studentObj.size());

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
    Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);

    // Iterate using YOUR hash keys
    for(int i = 0; i < studentObj.size(); i++){
       w.write(studentObj.get(i).getString());
       w.write(studentObj.get(i).getStudent());
    }

    w.close();

      catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("FILE IS NOT CREATED");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new Exception("CLASS NOT FOUND EXCPETION");
    }
}
```

And just write the data pulled from ObjectInputStream directly to the file